# Regex: Adding negative cases with lookaheads

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex from [here](https://github.com/chjj/marked/blob/master/lib/marked.js#L490):

```
/^_(?=\S)([\s\S]*?\S)_(?!_)|^\*(?=\S)([\s\S]*?\S)\*(?!\*)/
```

This regex is designed to match 2 underscores and the text between them. For example:

```
var regex = /^_(?=\S)([\s\S]*?\S)_(?!_)|^\*(?=\S)([\s\S]*?\S)\*(?!\*)/;
var string = '_omgbbq_';
regex.exec(string);
>>>["_omgbbq_", "omgbbq", undefined]
```

However, I want to add an additional rule - if there is a backslash before the underscore then it should ignore it. For example:

```
var string = '_omg\\_bbq_'
regex.exec(string)
>>>["_omgbbq_", "omgbbq", undefined]
```

What's the best way to add a negative case to this regex so that it ignores underscores which are followed by a backslash? My inclination is to use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but this regex is so complicated I am not sure where to insert it without messing anything up. Where in this regex can I add a lookahead to detect and ignore a negative case?

Comment: Sorry, did you mean `var string = "_omg\\_bbq_"`?

Comment: Ah yes, I certainly did. Will correct

Comment: You can use [`var regex = /^_(?=\S)([\s\S]*?[^\s\\])_(?!_)|^\*(?=\S)([\s\S]*?\S)\*(?!\*)/;`](https://jsfiddle.net/jg88bdrc/) I believe.

Comment: I'll test it out, one sec. Why not submit this as an answer?

Comment: It takes time to write an answer :) I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
var regex = /^_(?=\S)([\s\S]*?[^\s\\])_(?!_)|^\*(?=\S)([\s\S]*?\S)\*(?!\*)/;
                              ^^^^^^^
```

I expanded the `\S` to a negated character class `[^\s]` and added a `\` into it so that we do not match the closest `_` if it is preceded with a backslash.

If you need to also match strings like `*omg\*bbq*` (see the second alternative in the regex you have), you can use the same technique:

```
var regex = /^_(?=\S)([\s\S]*?[^\s\\])_(?!_)|^\*(?=\S)([\s\S]*?[^\s\\])\*(?!\*)/;
```

```js
var regex = /^_(?=\S)([\s\S]*?[^\s\\])_(?!_)|^\*(?=\S)([\s\S]*?[^\s\\])\*(?!\*)/g;
var string = "_omg\\_bbq_ ";
console.log(string.match(regex));
string = "*omg\\*bbq*";
console.log(string.match(regex));
```

Comment: Ended up having to remove the `\S` from the negated character class because it would fail the following case: `**bold **_italic _none **_bold and italic_**`. Changed the regex to: `/^_((?:__|[\s\S])+?[^\\])_|^\*((?:\*\*|[\s\S])+?[^\\])\*(?!\*)/`

Comment: I will check tomorrow, sorry, too sleepy.